# My dataset contains two tables i need to get division of FirstTable.Row2/SecondTable.Row5

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

My dataset contains two tables i need to get division of FirstTable.Row2/SecondTable.Row5

Comment: Could you be a little clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the types are the same and division is acceptable... and I am understanding your question:

```
DataSet ds = GetMyData();
// You should check here for there being at least 2 tables in the DataSet
// and that Table 1 has at least 2 rows and Table 2 has at least 5 rows.
var result = 
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["YourField"] / ds.Tables[1].Rows[4]["YourOtherField"];
```